# Rationality of intersection of algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, lie-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose that $G$ (defined over $\mathbb{Q}$) and $H$ (defined over $\mathbb{R}$) are two algebraic subgroups of a larger algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Assume that $G(\mathbb{R})$ and $H(\mathbb{R})$ are compact (and connected). If $G(\mathbb{R})\cap H(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then what we can say about $G$ and $H$? Is it true that either $H$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $G$ is contained in $H$?

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216466/rationality-of-intersection-of-algebraic-groups).

Comment: Does "defined over $Q$" means "definable over Q"? when you say algebraic subgroups, do you mean that $G$ is an $Q$-subgroup? an $R$-subgroup? do you mean that $H$ is an $R$-subgroup?

Comment: Can't say anything; what if $G_{\mathbf{R}} \cap H = 1$?  The hypotheses need to be made more specific.  What is the motivation?